# Blazor - how disable access to Account pages that are not used

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When we create a new project with individual user accounts authentication pages like:

> /Identity/Account/Manage/Externallogins

Are available even if such pages was not scaffolded and even if app is not ready to support that. Of course, we can remove navigation to such pages but I think that will be better to not allow to go to functionality that is not supported at all.
What is the easiest way to block such pages? Generate them and remove content? Put redirections for all of them to "page non exist (404)"?